# Matplotlib clipping first bar in hbar in half horizontally

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm struggling to understand why the first bar in a matplotlib hbar plot is being chopping in half horizontally. The yaxis label is also missing for that bar. Any idea of why this is happening?

Here is the script and attached is the output
[image: Output of attached script]

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import neptcon as nc
import sys
import pickle

fp = open("C:\Python27\Internal_reports\\shared.pkl")
shared = pickle.load(fp)

con = None

cur, con = nc.connect()
cur = con.cursor()   
scriptFile = open("C:\Python27\Internal_reports\Ann_report_sql\Den diff.sql", 'r')
script = scriptFile.read()
scriptFile.close()    
cur.execute(script.format(**shared))
items = cur.fetchall()
client, ship, imo, diff = zip(*items)
new_list = []
for item in diff:
    new_list.append(int(item))          
N = len( new_list )
x = range( N )   
n_groups = N
index = np.arange(n_groups)
fig = plt.figure()
f, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, N/2), sharex=False)
bar_width = 0.95
opacity = 0.5
G = nx.complete_graph(10)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

plt.yticks(index+(bar_width/2), ship, fontsize = 9)
ax1.yaxis.grid(True, which='major', color='0.95',linestyle='-')
ax1.set_ylim(0, N)
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
for a,b in zip(index,new_list):
    plt.text(b, a-0.2, str(b))  
    plt.barh(a,b,color=cm.autumn(1.*a/len(x)),edgecolor='white')
if N > 40:
    plt.savefig('{} quan_diff.pdf'.format(shared.get("cl")), format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
else:
    plt.savefig('C:\Python27\Internal_reports\plots\\quan_diff.png', bbox_inches='tight')

nc.closeCon()
```

Comment: what if you manually adjust y_lim to a wider range?

Comment: @Julien Excellent, that sent me in the right direction, I needed to reduce the min of ylim to a negative then reduce y-axis from 1 to zero. All looking good now